# Xcode wont load dylib when running on device

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, frameworks, dylib

Im having a very annoying problem when running on a device.

I added the MapKit framework and after that it has crashed every single time saying:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib
...
```

Ive tried everything, Ive added it in Embedded binaries, Ive deleted derived data, cleared cache, clean, Ive tried remove the MapKit from the project and the use of it in code, Ive checked Embedded content contains Swift code.

Ive tried everything but its still crashing, please help me!